# Angular: Render image if it is available. Otherwise render default image

Tags: angular

In my program, I am retrieved an image from an api.
The image path could be valid or invalid.
In my design below, the code will break if it returns an image that is not found.

I want to return a default image, called default-image.jpg if an image is not found in the url
http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185{{movie.poster_path}}. The default-image.jpg file is located in the assets folder.

app.component.html

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="box" *ngFor="let movie of _movieArray; let i = index">
        <div class="img"><img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185{{movie.poster_path}}" (error)="updateUrl($event)"></div>
        <br>
        <div class="title">{{movie.title}}</div>
        <br>
        <div class="overview">{{movie.overview}}</div>
        <br><br>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
updateUrl() {
    // need to update the src here, but I don't know how.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Answer is much simple than I think it is.

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="box" *ngFor="let movie of _movieArray; let i = index">
        <div class="img"><img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185{{movie.poster_path}}" onError="this.src='assets/default-image.jpg'"></div>
        <br>
        <div class="title">{{movie.title}}</div>
        <br>
        <div class="overview">{{movie.overview}}</div>
        <br><br>
    </div>
</div>
```